# How can I set a Parse objectId as a pointer in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I need to save some `PFObject` with two pointers. One is `createdBy` and it is equal to `PFUser.currentUser()`. The other is `card` and it is equal to my example variable, `s8HiwfvKtQ`. When I run this code, I get the following error:

```
[Error]: invalid type for key card, expected *Cards, but got string (Code: 111, Version: 1.7.1)
```

My code is here:

```
var ex = "s8HiwfvKtQ"

func addToWants() {
    let wants = PFObject(className:"Wants")
    wants["createdBy"] = PFUser.currentUser()
    wants["card"] = ex
    wants.save()
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to do a query (which is relatively expensive as you're hitting the server). Instead, create a *[placeholder for the object](https://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFObject.html#//api/name/objectWithoutDataWithClassName:objectId:)* just using the objectId and use that to populate the pointer.

Answer (score 1):

`wants["card"]` is a Cards object not String. You should get card by `ex`, like this:

```
wants["card"] = query.getObjectWithId("ParseObjectIDString")
```

Comment: The formatting is off. I'm not sure how to convert it to Swift.

Answer (score 1):

I think you pre-define your data schema in your **Parse** data browser and it detected that the type of `card` should be an instance of `Cards` instead of `String`. You will need to change your data schema in your data browser in order to make it through. That's what your error message says.

In **Parse**, it's fine for you to create data without predefining any data schemas. Once you have already pre-defined your data schema, you have to follow your rule.

Answer (score -1):

I figured it out. I had to do a query for the object, and use the result as the parameter for the "card" pointer.

```
var ex = "s8HiwfvKtQ"

func addToWants() {

    var query = PFQuery(className:"Cards")
    query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId("\(ex)") {
        (card: PFObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if error == nil && card != nil {
            let wants = PFObject(className:"Wants")
            wants["createdBy"] = PFUser.currentUser()
            wants["card"] = card
            wants.save()
        } else {
            println(error)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's intention then? Your post was talking about not being able to `String` as a value of key `card`. If you aimed to save `String` to `card`. You need to go to your data browser to change your data schema.